# How can I get the new lat, lang of the user whenever the user drags the pin anywhere using google map api

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm building a web app that actually allow the user to see the marker for a selected a address. Also, I'm trying to build a feature that when a user drag the pin it should update the lat, lang value. Though I was able to get the current location of a user using the code below but the big question is `How can I get the new lat, lang of the user whenever the user drags the pin anywhere`? Any response is much appreciated, thank you. Btw, I am using this addon https://github.com/asennikov/ember-g-map

`/component.js`

```
    getCurrentLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log(navigator.geolocation);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
         this.set('selectedLatitude', position.coords.latitude);
         this.set('selectedLongitude', position.coords.longitude);
         this.set('hasSelectedFromAutoCompleteOrCurrentLocation', true);

         this.reverseGeoCode(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude).then((resp) => {
           this.set('formattedAddress', resp);
         }).catch((error) => console.log(error));

       });
      } else {
        console.log("Your browser doesn't support geo location");
      }
    },
```

`/template.hbs`

```
    {{#g-map lat=cityLatitude lng=cityLongitude zoom=zoomValue options=mapOptions as |context|}}
      {{#if hasSelectedFromAutoCompleteOrCurrentLocation}}
        {{g-map-marker context lat=selectedLatitude lng=selectedLongitude onDrag=(action "getCurrentLocation") draggable=true zoom=zoomValue icon=myIcon}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/g-map}}
```

Comment: I believe `ondrag` would pass you the position info. (note: I don't know about `ember`)

Comment: I am already using `onDrag` and it works, but the value of `lat` and `lang` doest change

Comment: maybe there is a `center` property or something like that?

Comment: Accordingly to documentation `onDrag` should receive `lat` and `lng` attributes. If you are using the latest version and it's not receive that attributes, I would consider it as a bug, try to setup a minimal reproduction using an Ember Twiddle or CodeSandbox and report it as an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola @Mikelemuel, thank you for your question!

I have been able to solve your problem with a quick example application that I have created locally and I think part of the problem that you might be experiencing is that you are overloading `getCurrentLocation()` to do too many things  Let me explain...

Firstly I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do in your use case. I have made the assumption that because you're using the `navigator.geolocation` functionality that you want the map to initialise with the current location of the user and then they should be able to drag the icon around to pick a more specific location. Because of this I have moved the `navigator.geolocation` implementation to the `init()` function of the component and simplified the onDrag implementation to take the passed-in attributes.

```js
// app/components/map.js
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.set('selectedLatitude', position.coords.latitude);
        this.set('selectedLongitude', position.coords.longitude);
        this.set('hasSelectedFromAutoCompleteOrCurrentLocation', true);

        this.reverseGeoCode(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude).then((resp) => {
          this.set('formattedAddress', resp);
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error));

      });
    } else {
      console.log("Your browser doesn't support geo location");
    }
  },

  actions: {
    updateLocation(lat, lon) {
      this.set('selectedLatitude', lat);
      this.set('selectedLongitude', lon);
    },
  }
});
```

This will initially update the map with a marker for the current location and will then allow the user to drag the marker, which updates `selectedLatitude` and `selectedLatitude`. I have added an output to the template just to show this in action:

```html
<!-- app/templates/components/map.hbs -->
{{#g-map lat=53 lng=-7 zoom=8 options=mapOptions as |context|}}
  {{#if hasSelectedFromAutoCompleteOrCurrentLocation}}
    {{g-map-marker context lat=selectedLatitude lng=selectedLongitude onDrag=(action "updateLocation") draggable=true zoom=zoomValue icon=myIcon}}
  {{/if}}
{{/g-map}}

<p>Lat {{this.selectedLatitude}} Lon: {{this.selectedLongitude}}</p>
```

You will notice that I updated the `lat=cityLatitude lng=cityLongitude zoom=zoomValue` values in my example just so that it would show roughly where I am  that is roughly pointing at Ireland

Here is an example of it working:

[image: Example of a working map with draggable marker updating lat and long]

Note: I have already dragged the marker once so that I'm not revealing my exact location  but it did work as expected on initial load

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answer! :D :thumbs_up

Comment: Question, where did the `lat, lon` came from? How did the `updateLocation()` can receive such values that it doesn't defined somewhere? I tried it and it worked but just want to know where it came from hehe. Thank you!

Comment: Essentially what's happening is that we're passing a function into `onDrag` which is a part of the google maps API. when you drag on the map the function that you have passed into onDrag is called with the new Lat and Lon. Does that make sense? if you want more info you can check out the google map API documentation (not anything specifically to do with Ember)